# Create Vimscript To Repeat Substitution Until No More Matches Are Found

Tags: regex, vim

Is it possible to create a vimscript which performs a substitution repeatedly until no more matches are found?

In my case, I want to edit SVG files so that they contain only lines, no polylines or polygons.  So e.g. I want the string

```
<polyline points="0,1 2,3 4,5 6,7"/>
```

to become:

```
<line x1="0" y1="1" x2="2" y2="3"/>
<line x1="2" y1="3" x2="4" y2="5"/>
<line x1="4" y1="5" x2="6" y2="7"/>
```

My idea was to perform a substitution which takes the first pair of points out of a polyline and creates a line before the polyline with the first and second pair of points (if there are at least two).  This will be repeated until no more matches can be found, i.e. each polyline consists of one pair of points only.  Then the remaining polylines get deleted.

Maybe there is a simpler solution, using only one substitution to perform the task, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Do these SVG files have always this structure `0,1 2,3 4,5 6,7` ? meaning digit comma, digit space digit comma etc.

Comment: @Ibrahim I don’t know about always, but the ones created by Adobe Illustrator seem to behave this way...

Comment: how about something like this https://regex101.com/r/INVycP/3/

Comment: I didn't make this clear in the question, but the polyline elements can be of any length, they don't have to contain only 4 pairs of points, like in my example.  Thanks for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need vimscript to repeat until there are no matches! You can do this with normal mode keystrokes. This is a really useful trick. In general, you can do

```
qqqqq:s/foo/bar/<cr>@qq@q
```

Explanation:

```
qqq                         " Clear register 'q'
   qq                       " Start recording into register 'q'
     :s/foo/bar/<cr>        " Run the regex
                    @q      " Call macro 'q' (from within the macro 'q')
                      q     " Stop recording 
                       @q   " Call macro 'q'
```

Once `:s/foo/bar/<cr>` doesn't match, it will break the macro and stop it from running.

The regex you want is pretty complicated:

```
%s/\v(\<polyline points\=".{-})@<=(\d+),(\d+) (\d+),(\d+)(.*)/\4,\5\6\r<line x1="\2" y1="\3" x2="\4" y2="\5"\/>
```

`(\<polyline points\=".{-})@<=` makes it so that the rest of the line is preceded by `<polyline points="`, but that part matches with zero-width. Then, we look for two doubles of digits `(\d+),(\d+) (\d+),(\d+)` followed by anything `(.*)`. Then we replace everything after the first pair of digits with:

```
\4,\5\6\r<line x1="\2" y1="\3" x2="\4" y2="\5"\/>
```

The `\4,\5\6\r` is the second pair of digits, followed by the rest of the line, followed by a newline. After that is the new line you want.

This could be simpler with the `global` command:

```
g/polyline.*,.*,/s/\v(\d+),(\d+) (\d+),(\d+)(.*)/\3,\4\5\r<line x1="\1" y1="\2" x2="\3" y2="\4"\/>
```

This removes the messy `(\<polyline points\=".{-})@<=` by only running the regex on lines that match `polyline.*,.*,`, that is, a line containing *polyline* followed by two commas.

If you'd like to do this in vimscript, simply make a function that sets the register 'q', then calls it with `:norm @q`. For example:

```
function! SVGSplit()
  let @q=':%s/\v(\<polyline points\=".{-})@<=(\d+),(\d+) (\d+),(\d+)(.*)/\4,\5\6\r<line x1="\2" y1="\3" x2="\4" y2="\5"\/>'."\<CR>".'@q'
  normal @q
endfunction
```

Then you can do `:call SVGSplit()`.

For whatever reason, this didn't work with the `:g` version, and I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you think it is still possible to create a vimscript for this?  Since the regex commands are rather complicated, I'd like to have a `svgsplit.vim` file which I can execute from within any SVG file via `:source svgsplit.vim`.

Comment: I only know vimscript, but maybe this would rather be a job for e.g. Perl or Python though?

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out this can be done in Awk (gawk specifically) and the `FPAT` variable.

```
gawk -v FPAT='[0-9]+' '{for(i=1;i<=NF-3;i+=2){printf "<line x1=\"" $i "\" y1=\"" $(i+1) "\" x2=\"" $(i+2) "\" y2=\"" $(i+3) "\"/>\n";}}' file.txt
```

For readability:

```
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF-3;i+=2){
        printf "<line x1=\"" $i "\" y1=\"" $(i+1) "\" x2=\"" $(i+2) "\" y2=\"" $(i+3) "\"/>\n";
    }
}
```